# Passing an object along with url in mono touch

Tags: c#, ios, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I am new to iOS development using C#, want to make a post call to the server in which I want to send an object along with the service request.

Here is how I am currently making a call to load url in my UIWebView.

```
NSUrlRequest url= (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("http://www.xyz.com/Home/someAction/?userId="+userID+"&userName="+userPwd)));
```

But now in place of passing username and password in form of query string I want to pass an object of class User having some properties in query string

Can anybody suggest how to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What's a **Modal** ? How is this related to `UIWebView`. Shouldn't it be related to `OAuth` ?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pass a complex object instead of just parameters in a query string?

Comment: @stephane here Modal means a complex datatype, and it is related to UIWebView in the sense that when i make a request along with the complex object i want to load the response which i will get.

Comment: @valdetro yes that is preciously what i want.

Comment: If you want to send data along, `NSUrlRequest` is not the best choice.

Comment: @stephane then  how can i do it? give me some idea my main intention is to send data along and load the response in UIWebView.